# unable to setup existing laravel-4 application on my local machine

Tags: laravel-4, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, puphpet

I am new to laravel and recently i started working on a project already built in `laravel-4` , It's been 2 days i am banging my head with walls. Project require `Vagrant (1.6.3)` and `VirtualBox (4.3.12)` which i have installed. Below are the steps i've taken so far and finally i've reached to a point where i hit URL but after taking some to load it says page not found.

- after installing vagrant and vm i sucessfully issued `vagrant up`
- after that i successfully issued `vagrant ssh`
- ran `php artisan migrate` with success
- imported database correctly
- successfully ran `compass compile` from `public` dir
- created `vhost` entry in /etc/hosts and used the ip address mentioned in `puphpet/config.yaml` file say `192.168.10.10 mysite.dev`
- when i hit `mysite.dev` page keeps on loading for quite some time and nothing displays.

Please help me to get through this.

Apache2 config

```
# Security
ServerTokens OS
ServerSignature On
TraceEnable On

ServerName "vagrant"
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 120
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

User www-data
Group www-data

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>

DefaultType none
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
LogLevel warn
EnableSendfile Off

#Listen 80


Include "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load"
Include "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf"
Include "/etc/apache2/ports.conf"

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional "/etc/apache2/conf.d/*.conf"
Include "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf"
```

Below is the config.yaml

`vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/ubuntu1204-x64
        box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1204-x64
        hostname: null
        memory: '512'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.101
            forwarded_port:
                DmcuTDQMf9XI:
                    host: '6667'
                    guest: '22'
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
                setextradata:
                    VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root: 1
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: manifest.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            SQSPRoT1ouQC:
                source: ./projects/
                target: /var/www
                nfs: 'false'
        usable_port_range: 2200..2250
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    packages: {  }
    dot_files:
        -
            bash_aliases: null
    _prevent_empty: ''
mailcatcher:
    install: 0
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/bin
        log_path: /var/log/mailcatcher/mailcatcher.log
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: null`
`apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - php
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        N33AOVP4ozHQ:
            servername: ouiby.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.ouiby.dev
            docroot: /var/www/ouiby/public/
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            override:
                - All
            options:
                - Indexes
                - FollowSymLinks
                - MultiViews
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
    mod_spdy: 0
nginx:
    install: 0
    vhosts:
        hc5rSEdgYxzH:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome.dev
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '55'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
            - gd
            - curl
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: America/Chicago
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
drush:
    install: 0
    settings:
        drush.tag_branch: 6.x
mysql:
    install: '1'
    root_password: '123'
    adminer: 0
    databases:
        8OGu2emkRAUl:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: test
            host: localhost
            user: admin
            password: '123'
            sql_file: ''
postgresql:
    install: 0
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: 0
    root_password: '123'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
    version: '10.0'
mongodb:
    install: 0
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: 0
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
beanstalkd:
    install: 0
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: 0
    settings:
        port: '5672'`

Comment: is it running from the VM ? it can come from your site

Comment: i can access it using Ip address (assets dosent load though) , and i dont know how i can run this from vm....

Comment: do you use nginx/apache, look your web server config, it might be an issue there

Comment: i'm using apache, what possible issue you think i should look in apache....

Comment: can you paste your httpd.conf

Comment: I'm unable to locate httpd.conf, although i can find /etc/apache2/apache2.conf


I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS , It's actually installed by VM, i didn't do it

Comment: apache2.conf is also fine, it depends of your distrib

Comment: added apache2.conf, please check it

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your statements:

> Project require Vagrant (1.6.3) and VirtualBox (4.3.12)

Your project shouldn't care what version Vagrant and VirtualBox you have installed, as long as it meets those minimum requirements.

Thankfully, you're using my FOSS puphpet so I can help with more details!

Show us your config.yaml and I can help debug.

However - I'm going to tell you that 99% of the issues opened on my github repo related to this same problem are due to users not setting the Directory and FilesMatch directives correctly:

```
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_bsprdg6jr2c6:
            servername: awesome.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            docroot: /var/www/awesome
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            setenvif:
                - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_sopp5ivt1abc:
                    path: /var/www/awesome
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_nb10pakh7ocm:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
```

This is the most basic setup that will work with PHP from puphpet's gui.

What you want to look at are `apache.vhosts.{key}.docroot` and `apache.vhosts.{key}.directories.{key}.path` and make sure they match what's available within your VM. In this example, your `index.php` *must* be located at `/var/www/awesome/index.php` for this to work.

Comment: I've added `config.yaml` this version of config dosent contain `{key}.directories.{key}.path` , Please check it. Thx

Comment: @Khu-tech you're using a *very* old version of puphpet. You should consider upgrading.

Comment: As i emntioned i am new to this stuff, how would i upgrade this ? would it cause issues to vm or vagrant ? please help me in this. Thx